# Parse string from right-to-left in C

Tags: c, parsing, delimiter, right-to-left

I am trying to separate an IPV6 address from a port in C. The address and port will always be given by "'[' + address + ']:' + port", for example: "[2009:7a4d:80d2:33af:0000:0000]:6667". In python, to do this, I would do something similar to the following:

```
>>> thing = "[2009:7a4d:80d2:33af:0000:0000]:6667"
>>> print thing[-4:]
6667
>>> print thing[1:30]
2009:7a4d:80d2:33af:0000:0000
```

How do I do the equivalent of python's right-to-left parsing, i.e. [-4:], in C? And, preferably without using regex, how can I say in C that I would like everything between '[' and ']'?

Thanks for any help and advice!

Comment: So basically what you are looking for is a `substr` implementation in C?

Comment: I'm not all too familiar with PHP, but yes, I believe that is precisely what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

C does not have string manipulation built into the language, so you need to use a few functions. strrchr() searches for a given character from the end of the string. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
int main()
{
  char* thing = "[2009:7a4d:80d2:33af:0000:0000]:6667";
  char* a=strrchr(thing,']'); /* Find the last ']' */
  char address[128]; /* Make somewhere new to hold the address part */
  strncpy(address, thing+1, a-thing-1); /* copy (a-thing)-1 characters, starting from the second character of thing, into address */
  printf("port: %s\n",a+2); /* a+2 is two characters from the start of a (where we found the ']') */
  printf("address: %s\n",address); 
}
```

You can also write a '\0' into the string as in SashaN's answer, which effectively divides the original string in two. This won't work here as I used a string constant which can't be modified. Note that 'address' must be long enough to hold the address under all cases.

'a' and 'thing' are both pointers, so (a-thing) is used to give the difference (in characters) between the start of thing and the ']'.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* thing = "[2009:7a4d:80d2:33af:0000:0000]:6667";
char ipv6[30];
strncpy (ipv6, thing + 1, 29);
ipv6[29] = '\0';
```

It's crude, and only works with the fixed-string constraints you outlined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtok_r` for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *saveptr;

    char *address;
    char *port;

    address = strtok_r(argv[1], "[]", &saveptr);
    port = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr);

    puts(port);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that I haven't actually parsed it backwards, but that doesn't seem necessary from the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will return the substring between the firstmost and lastmost characters in a string, provided as parameter. The `exclusive` flag tells it whether or not to include those characters in the result.

I'm guessing some additional validation should be done before attempting `strncpy()`, so be careful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *substr_betweenchars(char *string, char begin, char end, int exclusive)
{
  char *left = strchr(string, begin);
  char *right = strrchr(string, end);
  char *result = 0;

  int a = left - string;
  int b = right - string;
  int n = b - a + 1 - (!!exclusive << 1);

  if (left && right)
  {
    result = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(result, left + !!exclusive, n);
  }

  return result;
}

int main(void)
{
  char string[] = "[2009:7a4d:80d2:33af:0000:0000]:6667";

  printf("%s\n", substr_betweenchars(string, '[', ']', 1));  
  printf("%s\n", substr_betweenchars(string, '[', ']', 0));
  printf("%s\n", substr_betweenchars(string, '8', '2', 1));  
  printf("%s\n", substr_betweenchars(string, '8', '2', 0));  

  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ gcc -Wall -o substr substr.c

$ ./substr
2009:7a4d:80d2:33af:0000:0000
[2009:7a4d:80d2:33af:0000:0000]
0d
80d2
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using `sscanf()` here like a regex?  It has a regex-like feature that could read the address from the formatted string quite nicely:

```
char str[] = "[2009:7a4d:80d2:33af:0000:00000]:6667";
char addr[30];
sscanf(str, "[%29[^]]]", addr);
addr[29] = '\0';
printf("%s", addr); /* 2009:7a4d:80d2:33af:0000:0000 */
```

Otherwise you could just scan through the string looking for the open and close brackets and copy the contents in between as some of the other answers have shown.

Answer (score -2):

man string(3C)

```
portstr = strrchr(ipv6str, ':');
if (portstr != NULL) {
    *portstr = '\0';
    portstr++;
}
```